# After installing CUDA on Tegra Tx1 and sourcing the bashrc it will not find NVCC

Tags: linux, bash, cuda, nvcc, tegra

After flashing the Tegra Board the CUDA Drivers (including the CUDA compiler nvcc) must be installed. To do so I simply used the given format:

```
sudo ./cuda-l4t.sh .cuda-repo-l4t-8-0-local_8.0-76_arm64.deb 8.0 8-0
```

and

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

but when I enter `nvcc -V` it does not show the wanted specification about the nvcc, it just tells me that the command was not recognized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should check if CUDA was really installed!

To do so go to the path:

```
/usr/local
```

There must be a cuda folder or a folder named cuda-8-0 or whatever version you installed. Remember the name and the path. 
Now check your bashrc by using `gedit/vi/nano/vim` whatever you prefer:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

Go to the bottom of the file. There should be some exports regarding the `PATH` Variable and the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Check if it was written to these variables and then overwritten again.

You must export the Path to the bin folder of your CUDA application and the Path to lib64 folder.

To do so at the bottom of the bashrc must stand something like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin: ....
export LD_LIBARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64: ....
```

After the double dots may follow some other paths. make sure that the path given to the cuda application is the correct one and that it is not overwritten again.

After you made the correct changed do not forget to source the basrhc again.